# Is a using declaration legal inside a switch statement before any cases?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

The following code compiles fine in GCC 9.1 (-Wall -Wextra -Werror -g) without any warnings or errors, but clang-tidy gives me  `OCDFAInspection warning: unreachable code`. Since GCC has all these addons like integer ranges in switch cases for example, I am concerned, that this might be another *addon* and not actually valid C++.

So is the following code legal in C++ (17 if that matters)?

```cpp
namespace foo {
    void bar() {}
}

int main() {
    int n = 42;

    switch (n) {
        using namespace foo; // <- is this valid?
        case 42: 
            bar();
            break;
        default: 
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `switch` statement is a fun one, because the syntax of it is something like

```
switch (expression) statement
```

And here `statement` can be ***any*** statement. The compiler treats the keyword `case`, `default` and `break` differently in the scope of a `switch` but otherwise you can have any statement you want, including block statements (curly-brace enclosed lists of statements) with anything you want.

The problem with generic statements outside of a case is that they won't be executed. The generated code will jump to a specific `case` label (or the `default` case), skipping any statements that are not part of a case.

But for this specific case it is, as mentioned in a comment, a false positive. The `using` directive as used here is directing the compiler to add the namespace `foo` to its symbol look-up, but it doesn't itself create or generate any executable code.

Comment: The warning is a clang-tidy bug then?

Comment: @nada - A false positive. A using directive only affects name lookup inside the block scope. Its "reach-ability" is meaningless.